# Is there an Adobe Flash Builder counterpart IDE for HTML5?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, html, ide

We use Adobe Flash Builder to create interactive web applications powered by Flex. Now we are looking for alternatives that will let us have the same ease of development with regards to UI designing plus coding catered for HTML5. Is there such an IDE? If so, what's it called?

The main interest is to easily create web apps but instead of running on Flash, it will be running on HTML5 technology.[RealStudio's web publishing IDE](http://www.realsoftware.com/web/) would have been nice. It almost has all, save for the fact that it requires fastCGI or CGI to run whereas our aim is to crreate PHP-based apps.

The most important thing is to give the users a desktop-like experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aptana](http://aptana.com/), with [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/).

If you simply like the Eclipse platform Flash Builder is built upon, you can use [Eclipse Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/development/).

[Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html) may also package HTML / JavaScript with Dreamweaver.

Or, there's [Adobe Edge](http://edge.adobe.com/whatisedge.html).

> Adobe Edge is a powerful, intuitive tool for creating stunning
>   animated and interactive content using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript.
>   Edge is intuitive and has powerful features that can save time and
>   headaches. Content made with Edge runs gracefully on mobile devices
>   and desktops, expanding your reach on the modern web.

Comment: I've seen Adobe Edge before but as far as I can tell, it's mmore of a Flash Professional counterpart than a Flash Builder one. It's more geared towards creating animations than creating applications. Also, can you elaborate on the Adobe AIR part? How will it package HTML/JS?

Comment: t's not the Eclipse platform, it's the fact that it's like developing a desktop application because there are ComboBoxes, Buttons, DataGrids, Checkboxes, etc. THat can easily be popped into the app we're making.

Comment: Just had a quick look at Sencha and I tink it's the one I'm looking for!

Comment: There is also Maqetta(still in beta). It can run on your computer or on a web server http://maqetta.org